# recognize very low level picture and color it in plain black in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, label, gaussian

I'm working on an automated "bug count" algorithm and I'm wondering how I can recognize a very low level of contrast (no additional bugs on pad - assume camera is at the same position and ligh conditions very similar) if I subtract two pics from each other, i won't get a clean black image due to the fact the light conditions will be minimally different. Now I apply a gaussian filter and mahotas.thresholding.otsu() to draw out where there is a bug (put a white blob over top) and then I use ndimage.label() to count them.

However, if my input image "cropbugs.jpg" is very dark grey, I get some random output after applying otsu() and my label() function returns a random bug count number. How do I recognize if my image is very dark grey or low in contrast and just set bug count to 0?
Thanks

My code so far looks like:

```
bug_img = mahotas.imread('cropbugs.jpg')
pylab.gray()

bug_img = ndimage.gaussian_filter(bug_img, 6)#8
T = mahotas.thresholding.otsu(bug_img)
pylab.imshow(bug_img > T)
labeled,nr_objects = ndimage.label(bug_img > T)
print "Bug Count: "+str(nr_objects)
pylab.imshow(labeled)
pylab.jet()
pylab.show()
```

Comment: if you put the image in greyscale and get the stddev of the colors, I would think that would put you close to where you want to be.

Comment: Actually combine `bug_img.mean()` with `bug_img.std()` to decide whether the image is too dark (or with low contrast) or not. Problem solved.

Comment: Btw, you can use (recent versions of) mahotas for both guassian_filtering and labeling. so you don't need ndimage.

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple ways of approaching this problem

1. (This was the suggestion in the comments).
   Define some fixed rule of the type based on the mean value, the standard deviation, the maximum value or some combination. You will end up with a test like one of the following:

   ```
   bug_img.mean() + 2*bug_img.std() < THRESHOLD
   bug_img.std() < THRESHOLD
   bug_img.max() < THRESHOLD
   sorted(bug_img.ravel())[-10] < THRESHOLD
   ```
2. Use a classification system based on texture features (see [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505754/248279) earlier).
3. Go ahead and use `label` as if everything was good and then **post-filter** the results. For example:

   ```
   labeled,nr_objects = mahotas.label(bug_img > T)
   sizes = mahotas.labeled.labeled_size(labeled)
   good_objects = (MIN_BUG_SIZE <= sizes) & (sizes <= MAX_BUG_SIZE)
   print np.sum(good_objects)
   ```